# Convert LAMP application to be distributed as a Windows MSI

Tags: php, mysql, windows, linux, windows-installer

I have recently completed a web based application for a client running on a LAMP system - Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP.  However, the spec has been changed and rather than the application be available over the web, the client now wishes it to be only available internally via their windows network.  Is it possible to set up apache, php, mysql on Windows, install my web app including mysql database and PHP code and then create an MSI that can be distributed on a CD ROM etc and installed on a Windows network?

Comment: Does it mean you still have to setup one server for database/apache but limited only to local network connections? Or does it mean you want to install whole stack (web server and database) on every workstation and use it only locally on that computer?

Comment: It would be limited to only one server (a windows server), but accessible from any browser enabled PC on the local network

Comment: You could set up a WAMP server for it.  The OS doesn't make as big of a difference as you may think.  The AMP part of it is what is important.  As far as making an MSI, I have no clue why that is necessary and it's not really possible unless you make it something other than a web app...

Comment: The MSI aspect of this problem is for ease of installation by the network admins.  I understand installing XAMPP or WAMP to provide the environment, but would prefer that the environment and app could be installed together rather than as separate entities.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be XAMPP ( http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp.html ).

But I guess it will be harder to programm/generate the MSI (eg WiX) than to use another approach like installing xampp and then placing your php/mysql files correctly in there.

You could also install XAMPP on your PC, setup everything fine, and zip it back up.
Customer would then need to install XAMPP and overwrite the files with the content of your zip.